# How can I write the Chinese enumeration comma "、" on Win10 keyboard?

Tags: technology

I found out that I can write the Chinese colon "：" with Shift + (key right from L).

Now I need to know how to write the enumeration comma. The existing Q&A threads did not help.

I would be glad about an answer! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the third key on the right of "M". On the German QWERTZ keyboard layout it should be a "-".

[image]

Suggestion: since what you call "Win10 keyboard" has many different versions according to the country, it always helps to describe the one you are using as well as the input method (that in your case, I guess, is the Win10 default).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know how I could overlook that!

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>\</kbd>(key on the left or below the <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) or <kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work.